# Cannot get classic ASP app to connect to database

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

We have an application which we are attempting to revive that was written in classic ASP in 2010. So far, I've done the following:

- I created a Microsoft Server 2016 instance on Amazon EC2
- I installed IIS Server
- I created the website inside the IIS Manager, added/linked the files, and successfully ran the application on `http://localhost`
- I installed SQL Server 2017 and imported the DB Backup (and successfully created the database)
- I created a SQL Server user and tested that I can access the DB using the created database user
- I enabled SQL Server Login Authentication and Windows Authentication Mode
- I added the connection to IIS Manager.
- I confirmed that web.config.xml has the proper information.

Im getting the following error:

```
2018-01-21 01:36:16 ::1 POST /intranet/process.asp |178|80004005|[Microsoft][ODBC_SQL_Server_Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL_Server_does_not_exist_or_access_denied. 80 - ::1
```

I noticed in the code theres a file that has a Session config for a database connection that doesnt look the same.

Im not sure what to do at this point. We need to figure out how to connect this database to the application

Heres my web.config.xml in the root:

```xml
<configuration>
<appSettings />
<connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Server=server\SQLEXPRESS;Database=dbname;User ID=dbuser;Password=dbpass" name="SqlServer" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Here's my web.config.xml inside the intranet folder which is for an admin area:

```
<add name="WEB"
    connectionString="Server=server\SQLEXPRESS;Database=dbname;User ID=dbuser;Password=dbpass"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I noticed a file `global.asa` that has this:

```
Sub Session_OnStart
       Session("ConnectString") = "Server=adifferentserver;Database=adifferentdatabase;UID=adifferentuser;PWD=adifferentpassword;Driver={SQL Server};"
```

This is my first time using ASP so you'd have to guide me for what other files you need.

Comment: Will you please provide an example of the VB/C# instantiating a connection to the DB, as well as the connection strings?

Comment: My dude, how do you spend almost 9 years on stackoverflow and not know that you should post your code with your question?

Comment: why have you tagged asp.net if it's classic asp?

Comment: Well that is as clear as mud - *"Im not sure what to do at this point."*. After reading that either do I, good luck if that is how you structure a question on [so].

Comment: @JacobH I was extremely ill when creating this question. Ill have the code posted shortly.

Comment: @Lankymart I was extremely ill when creating this question. Ill have the code posted shortly.

Comment: @jkushner I’m sorry to hear you are not feeling well. Maybe next time wait until you’re feeling yourself again, then post a question. If you think about it, it won’t get answered any quicker then if you had waited or even began composing it and left it in a draft state. Again, hope you start feeling better soon.

Comment: @JacobBarnes done

Comment: @Lankymart please see updated question

Answer (score 1):

The `global.asa` file in Classic ASP acts as an initialisation script it is commonplace to set long-running variables such as `Application` and `Session` variables there.

If this file contains a connection string variable then that is the value to change to your migrated database. At the moment `process.asp` is using `Session("ConnectString")` and ADODB is trying to locate `adifferentserver` using the SQL Server provider and failing. Once you correct the connection string using the required provider and server, database combination the page should work.

The other two values come from the `web.config` which was brought in with IIS 7.0 and above, it's designed for Microsoft .Net and Classic ASP does not know about connection strings configured inside it. The likelihood is there is another web application that uses ASP.Net that was making use of those connection strings.